# Tool to monitor rankings

Tags: seo, google, ranking

I'm searching for a tool that can give me the page number (Google) and position a given web page scores for a given keyword.

E.g. Searching for the term "foo" the tool will show third page, second position if in that moment the said web page is second on the third page on Google. This has to be in real time since rankings change frequently.

The webmasters tool doesn't give me an accurate information if the search result is not within the first three pages.

Answer (score 1):

[There are tons of tools out there](http://www.google.com/search?sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=check+google+rankings). A free one I use is [Google Monitor](http://www.cleverstat.com/en/google-monitor-query.htm). Basic and straight forward no extra crap tied to it.

Comment: Not what I was looking for. Google Monitor works with some keywords not all (sometimes it doesn't even work) returning "No results", and, exactly as Webmasters tools it returns the position not the page number. The reason I asked wasn't so that someone can link a Google search. There are tons of tools for SEO, and a lot of them are junk. I don't have time to waste testing and was hoping someone would share what they used. Thanks, I'll keep looking.

Comment: The page number usually isn't returned because it's easy to figure out: ranking / 10. And I'm surprised you've had bad results with that tool. It's been good to me for years. But it happens. Good luck in your search.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried [SEM Rush](http://www.semrush.com)? I use this professionally and it's great. You need to pay for the full service but there is also a free service that is limited to *n* searches per day.

Answer (score 0):

http://www.seomoz.org/
very impressive tool, but expensive

Answer (score 0):

I've used WebCEO (.com). It's quite extensive and too much for a non-SEO guy like me. The free version will allow only five keywords at a time.