# SEO - New web page are not getting indexing

Tags: search-engine-indexing

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to know that my site is getting index/rank by search engine](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/12706/how-to-know-that-my-site-is-getting-index-rank-by-search-engine)

Hi
I have uploaded dozen of new web page(those are xxx.html file) one month ago, but I can't find them on Google/Yahoo search result, how can I know that they are/aren't indexed by Google/Yahoo?

Answer (score 0):

One idea, you can check your hosting provider's web logs to see if it has been crawled by the google bot.  Also, have you submitted your sitemap to the engines?

If you post a link to one of the pages in question maybe we can help find out for you?